# MVC SPA + Knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have just recently be tasked with creating an SPA. So, I created a new project and selected SPA and found that it loaded all the files I needed including this knockout.js.

I am new to knockout.js so I watched a few videos and I get the idea, but the SPA project just doesn't seem to compute to me as it isn't a **Single Page Application** because you have to go to a new URL to login, register, authorise, manage account, etc (you get the idea).

So, looking at the code for the index page I can see a view model for the homeView. It looks like this:

```
function HomeViewModel(app, dataModel) {
    var self = this;

    self.myHometown = ko.observable("");

    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#home', function () {
            // Make a call to the protected Web API by passing in a Bearer Authorization Header
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: app.dataModel.userInfoUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + app.dataModel.getAccessToken()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    self.myHometown('Your Hometown is : ' + data.hometown);
                }
            });
        });
        this.get('/', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#home') });
    });

    return self;
}

app.addViewModel({
    name: "Home",
    bindingMemberName: "home",
    factory: HomeViewModel
});
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
<!-- ko with: home -->

<!-- removed HTML to make it concise -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

now, from the look of this (correct me if I am wrong) the **with** handle states that if there is a variable called **home**, then display it (I assume this is what the bindingMembername is).

So, seeing that I can guess that if I added another partial page and included it. I could created a view model like this:

```
function DrawViewModel(app, dataModel) {
    var self = this;

    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#draw', function () {
            app.home = null;
        });
    });

    return self;
}

app.addViewModel({
    name: "Draw",
    bindingMemberName: "draw",
    factory: DrawViewModel
});
```

so, in theory because this sets the app.home to null whenever anyone navigates to #draw, then the home partial will not be displayed, similarly I could added app.draw = null to the sammy route for the homeViewModel to hide the draw partial.

My issue with this, is that it will get massively complicated the more viewModels I create. So, is there something I am missing? Is there an easier way of doing this?

My ultimate goal is to move all the pages to be SPA (including the login/register pages).

Cheers in advance,
/r3plica

Comment: I have no idea why you sent that link. I know each ViewModel is not a new page, the page is the first page that loaded (in my case Index.cshtml) and I am trying to pull in content using hash tags

Comment: Just as a heads up, I have used KO based frameworks for a couple of years, but having moved to Angular found it's much easier. Even big frameworks such as Durandal are moving over and away from KO (see - http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/04/angular-and-durandal-converge.html). Here's a good tutorial to get you started. It got our team understanding a lot in a very short space of time - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM.

Comment: This is very broad to answer shortly, but the main idea is to put your `Sammy` navigation to `app` (which holds an array of pages and currently selected page in `ko.observable`). Then, on `layout.html` you'll have a ko template, that will use a view model of currently selected page. So, when an url changes, in your `Sammy` callback you just change the current page, and ko will change the template content automatically. So all the work with pages and navigation is contained in one place - `app`.

Comment: Here, I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rnnf9n4/) with basic principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bit of messing around I found out how to do this.
Basically I rewrote the AddView method and made it look like this:

```
// Other operations
self.addViewModel = function (options) {
    var viewItem = new options.factory(self, dataModel),
        navigator;

    // Add view to AppViewModel.Views enum (for example, app.Views.Home).
    self.Views[options.name] = viewItem;

    // Add binding member to AppViewModel (for example, app.home);
    self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.view() !== viewItem) {
            return null;
        }

        return new options.factory(self, dataModel);
    });

    if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            self.view(viewItem);
        };
    }

    // Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
    self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
};
```

are you can see, if check to see if the current held view is different to the one I am adding. If it is, then I return null (which is how I get it to hide any views I am not using).
To answer my question further, I needed a way of working out how to direct to the login page if the user was not logged in.

Again in **app.viewmodel.js** I added a few observable properties:

```
// UI state
self.user = ko.observable(null);

self.loggedIn = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.user() !== null;
});
```

and in my new **login.viewmodel.js** I added this function:

```
// Operations
self.login = function () {
    self.loggingIn(true);

    dataModel.login({
        grant_type: "password",
        username: self.userName(),
        password: self.password()
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.userName && data.access_token) {
            app.navigateToLoggedIn(data.userName, data.access_token, self.rememberMe());
        } else {
            //self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        dataModel.displayError(jqXHR);
    }).always(function () {
        self.loggingIn(false);
    });
};
```

the important bit here is the **app.naviateToLoggedIn** method. This is located in the **app.viewmodel.js** and looks like this:

```
// UI operations
self.navigateToLoggedIn = function (userName, accessToken, persistent) {
    if (accessToken) {
        dataModel.setAccessToken(accessToken, persistent)
    }

    self.user(new UserViewModel(self, userName, dataModel));
    self.navigateToHome();
};
```

the userViewModel is dead simple:

```
function UserViewModel(app, name, dataModel) {
    var self = this;

    // Data
    self.name = ko.observable(name);

    // Operations
    self.logOff = function () {
        dataModel.logout().done(function () {
            app.navigateToLoggedOff();
        }).fail(function (jqHXR) {
            dataModel.displayError(jqHXR);
        });
    };

    return self;
}
```

and finally, to get our initial load right, in the **home.viewmodel.js** js file, I have this sammy declaration:

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#home', function () {
        if (app.loggedIn()) {
            app.navigateToHome();
        } else {
            window.location.hash = "login";
        }
    });
    this.get('/', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#home') });
});
```